# Npm run dev stuack

Tags: node.js, laravel

I have installed the laravel/ui node.js for laravel faramework but when I want to compile laravel/ui sass fiels with
$ npm run dev
it stuck at APP_URL

> dev
> vite

Port 3000 is in use, trying another one...

vite v2.9.14 dev server running at:

> Local: http://localhost:3001/
> Network: use `--host` to expose

ready in 933ms.

Laravel v9.19.0

> APP_URL: http://localhost

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And what is your question?!

Comment: That is because Laravel 9 does not use Mix anymore. Now it uses Vite.
All you have to do  is remove Vite and install Mix. You can learn how to [migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix)